# Python write function is not writing last entry

Tags: python, csv

Here is a simplified version of my code. I am trying to write to a file using:

```
fileName = "missing.csv"
for x in range (0,5):
    print(x)
    saveData = open(fileName, "a")
    saveData.write(str(x)+'\n')
    saveData.close
```

The console prints:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

... as it should. However, when I open missing.csv it only contains:

```
0
1
2
3
```

**NO** last entry (the 4).

Any Ideas? Please advise.

Comment: Try `.close()` instead of `.close`. Also, I'm seeing 0 1 2 3 4 in the text file when running this.

Comment: Aghrr. . .this is correct, add the () to .close. There are more sophisticated answers below too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use  context manager you do not need to worry about close:

```
fileName = "missing.csv"
for x in range(0, 5):
    print(x)
    with open(fileName, "a") as save_data:
        save_data.write(str(x) + '\n')
```

And if you do not want to close the file after every operation, you can open and close it only once like:

```
fileName = "missing.csv"
with open(fileName, "a") as save_data:
    for x in range(0, 5):
        print(x)
        save_data.write(str(x) + '\n')
```

Comment: You could also put the loop inside the context manager to open the file **once**...

Comment: And you can also use string formatting to get rid of the manual cast ''.format()

Comment: @StephenRauch sorry, wrong post. I was on my phone and didn't dring the morning coffee

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the error you made in your code (missing the `()` to `.close`), you could use a context manager:

```
fileName = "missing.csv"
for x in range (0,5):
    print(x)
    with open(fileName, "a") as saveData:
        saveData.write(str(x)+'\n')
```

There's an implicit call to `.close()` at the exit of the `with..` block.

Answer (score 2):

No need to open/close file in loop, open it once and also close once. Apart from this you are missing `()` from `close` function.

```
fileName = "missing.csv"
saveData = open(fileName, "a")
saveData.write("\n".join( map(str, range(0,5)) ))
saveData.close()
```

If you preferred to use context.

```
fileName = "missing.csv"
with open(fileName, "a") as save_data:
   save_data.write("\n".join( map(str, range(0,5)) ))
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with this python code.  Something else is wrong.

Delete missing.csv and try again.  I suspect 0 1 2 3 are left over from a previous run of this and missing.csv is not actually updating.

Could be a permissions issue.  Check the file permissions to see if the user running the script has permissions.  I.E. make sure the group isn't wrong, the owner isn't wrong, and the actual rwx values aren't wrong.